# wireless LAN soft blocked on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, 13.10, bluetooth, lan

I've troubles with Bluetooth and with LAN.
When I digit:

```
rfkill list all

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

When I digit:   lspci -v

00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Complex
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Complex
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0

00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7600G] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7600G]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
    Memory at c0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=256]
    Memory at feb00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: radeon

00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity HDMI Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity HDMI Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
    Memory at feb44000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at feb48000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 7800
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 45
    I/O ports at f190 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f180 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f170 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f160 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f150 [size=16]
    Memory at feb50000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 18
    Memory at feb4f000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci

00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 17
    Memory at feb4e000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 18
    Memory at feb4d000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci

00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 17
    Memory at feb4c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 14)
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller
    Flags: 66MHz, medium devsel
    Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus

00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH IDE Controller (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH IDE Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 17
    I/O ports at 01f0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 03f4 [size=1]
    I/O ports at 0170 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 0374 [size=1]
    I/O ports at f100 [size=16]
    Kernel driver in use: pata_atiixp

00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller
    Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
    Memory at feb40000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0

00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=64

00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 18
    Memory at feb4b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci

00:14.7 SD Host controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SD Flash Controller (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SD Flash Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 39, IRQ 16
    Memory at feb4a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci

00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d0000000-00000000d00fffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:15.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: fe900000-feafffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 0
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 1
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 2
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 3
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp

00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 4
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 5
    Flags: fast devsel

02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 07)
    Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Device 0123
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
    Memory at d0004000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device 2b87
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at fea40000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Memory at fea30000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci

03:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device 2787
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at fea20000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Memory at fea10000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Memory at fe900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Expansion ROM at fea00000 [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Thank you  for all the help

Comment: Can you change it with: sudo rfkill unblock all? If so, we can make it persistent.

Comment: ok done and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the soft block permanently, please open a terminal and do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Right above exit 0, add a single line:

```
rfkill unblock all
```

Proofread carefully, save and close gedit. You should be all set.